# Get Facebook friends phone number

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Currently, im using ruby gem `Koala` and can get a list of user friends, but i can't find any way to fetch phone numbers from friend list. Is this even possible? Didn't find any information about this in the facebook documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i get the user's friend's phone number using graph api?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8360625/can-i-get-the-users-friends-phone-number-using-graph-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access phone information via the Graph API, either for the current user or for their friend.

You can see the browse API here: [Facebook API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)